# Wait for RestKit Object Manager to finish init

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, initialization, restkit

I have a class called `RestKitManager` that does the following:

```
+ (void)configureRestKit {
    RKObjectManager *sharedManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURLString];

    sharedManager.mappingProvider = [[IKObjectMappingProvider alloc] init];
    sharedManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    sharedManager.router = [[IKObjectRouter alloc] init];
}
```

`[RestKitManager configureRestKit]` is called in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

The problem is that in my first view controller, I have a call to my object manager to load stuff.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/list/brand" objectMapping:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Brand class]] delegate:self];
NSLog(@"%@",[RKObjectManager sharedManager]);
```

and I get:

```
2012-03-18 20:04:37.252 iK9[3668:207] (null)
2012-03-18 20:04:37.258 iK9[3668:207] I restkit:RKLog.m:30 RestKit initialized...
2012-03-18 20:04:37.264 iK9[3668:207] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:369 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x6ebb270 host=0.0.0.0 isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=620604 reachabilityFlags=-R -----l->
```

So essentially, it appears that the `sharedManager` has not finished initialization before I try to use it.

How can I make the app wait for the initialization to finish? I was not aware that this initialization was being performed in the background in `RestKit`. This is an ARC project.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I listen to `RKReachabilityWasDeterminedNotification` and then proceed with any further initialization that needs network access. Listen to this notification and update your view controller when it arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tutorial? http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/

it was pretty helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was once again, I created my own `MainWindow` and did not connect the `AppDelegate` to the `File's Owner`, nor did I set `File's Owner` to class `UIApplication`. After doing so my problems were resolved.